# What's a trick spider?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is one of the definitions for the word "trick"
b. (as modifier): a trick spider.

I looked on the internet but could not find the answer for what it is.

Comment: That's not much context to go on, but I would interpret that as a _fake_ spider (intended to scare someone).

Comment: What is the source of the definition? Was that just an example within a definition?

Comment: Without more I would have thought of some kind of performing spider, the way that there have been jumping flea shows in the past and other similar things.

Comment: Some dictionary websites, like Collins, use examples automatically gathered by algorithm. Sometimes odd usages will creep in. Googling the exact phrase "trick spider" seems to mostly give results about a prank involving a fake spider in a box.

Comment: [M-W *adjective* definition 1. a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trick)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the defintion from [collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trick) which can be found on "The free dictionary" for example.

The full definition of sense 2 is:

> 2. a. a mischievous, malicious, or humorous action or plan; joke: *the boys are up to their tricks again.*
>    b. (as modifier): *a trick spider.*

The meaning of sense 2b is the same as in 2a, but used as modifier.

And "a trick spider" is not the definition, but an example of this use.

It means, therefore, a joke that has the form of a spider.  That is, it is an object that has been made to look like a spider, and may be hidden in a box in some way so that it scares the person who opens the box. It is a prank involving a fake spider.

Comment: Thank you James :)